# How to use regular expression extract data not followed by something with pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I just want to extract the years, but not the number. How can I define not followed by XXX?

I made the following example, but the result is always a literal more than I expected.

```
text = ["hi2017", "322017"]
text = pd.Series(text)
myPat = "([^\d]\d{4})"

res = text.str.extract(myPat)
res
```

Then I get the result:

```
0    i2017
1      NaN
dtype: object
```

Actually, I just want to get "2017", but not "i2017", how can I do it?

PS. The "322017" should not be extracted, because it is not a year, but a number

Comment: What would the result be for "322017"?

Comment: The 322017 should not be extracted, because it is not a year

Comment: What do you define as a year?

Comment: according to the regex any entry that matches 4 digits.

Comment: actually 4 digital number, where the beginning should only 1 or 2, somehow like [12]\d{3}, for simplicity, here just ignored the format of year, I only consider 4 digital numbers.

Comment: By your definition, `322017` should result in `2201`. See my answer below.

Comment: `(?<!\d)[1-9]\d{3}(?!\d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)
```

which returns 2017 and is based almost entirely on the comment by @PauloAlmeida

Comment: I use python 3.5, but I got the error: ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

Comment: Give the updated answer a try, which places the result into a capture group.

Comment: This time both return the "NaN"

Comment: @JimSimson Did you test this? You should use negative lookbehind and lookahead: `'(?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d)'`. In particular, 'hi2017' fails with positive lookahead because it needs a character after the digits.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida yeah! I think, this is the right answer. :D

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, Tested it here: https://regex101.com/ using the Python engine. Is it different?

Comment: @JimSimson I just tested on that site with the Python engine and if you use the string `hi2017` there is no match. If you use `hi2017x` you get one.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, Ah, I had been using the entire text of his answer. I'll modify my answer, but if you want to post your own I'll pull mine. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Jim Simson No, go ahead and modify it. It's your idea, I just changed a couple of characters :)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida thanks. I'm glad we got to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you need only year, defined as 4 digits followed by non-number.

`"(?:[a-z]+)(\d{4})$"` works for me. (which means 4 digits followed by more than one character & the 4 digits are the last characters of the string)

```
text = ["hi2017", "322017"]
text = pd.Series(text)
myPat = "(?:[a-z]+)(\d{4})$"

res = text.str.extract(myPat)
```

#### Output:

```
print(res)
'''
0    2017
1     NaN
'''
```

Comment: But you still at first extracted redundant words at first, then, query by the group id...

Comment: `(?!a)b` Since `b` can never be `a`, there is no use having `(?!a)` since it is always positive when there is a `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You want 4-digit numbers where the first digit is either a 1 or a 2. This translates to all the numbers between 1000 to 2999, inclusive.

The regex for this is: `(1[0-9]{3})|(2[0-9]{3})`

This will get all the numbers between 1000 and 2999, inclusive within a string.

In your case, `hi2017` will result in `2017`. Additionally, `322017` will result in `2201`. This is also a valid year as per your definition.

Comment: I mean the year number should be 4 digital number and "not followed" by a number. In case of 322017, you can see, 2201 followed by 3.

Comment: I like the year range theory. If this were a scientific paper though, it might be speculating about what will happen in 4519 (the end of the world?).

Answer (score -1):

Regexr is a great online tool http://regexr.com/3ghcq

```
myPat = "(\d{4})"
```

Comment: If you use this one, then, you will also extract the 3220 from 322017, this is not wished, because it it can be an ID number.